# Mostrar ceros a la izquiera de un entero en C++

Tags: c++

Hola tengo un entero de 4 digitos el cual a veces por ejemplo será envede que a veces tendrá ceros a su izquierda pero el problema está qe no se como mostrar los ceros a la izquierdas supongamos que yo tengo el entero siguiente:

```
0382
```

Como podría hacer para mostrarlo con un cout o un printf los ceros de su izquierda ya que mi numero por ejemplo será de cuatro caracteres.
O a veces tendrá mas cero como podré mostrar los ceros de la izquierda.
En mi intento hare un cout:

```
int i;
i=0382;
cout << i;
```

Pero me lo mostrara como 382 como podría hacer yo para mostrar estos ceros?

Comment: parce to string

Comment: No sé si será lo que quieres, también soy usuario de Java y no conozco C# pero si simplemente necesitas mostrar los ceros en pantalla puedes meter un pequeño algoritmo que saque el número de cifras que contiene y si no es de 4 añade los 0 necesarios mostrándonos los ceros + el número en cuestión . Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: Como curiosidad, los literales numéricos que empiezan con un único cero (`0`) a la izquierda son literales octales, así que el número `0382` es 382 en base octal... el cuál no existe porque el `8` no es un dígito octal válido y el código fallará al compilar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puede hacer uso de [`cout.fill`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fill/) y [`cout.width`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/width/).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here

    int i;
    i = 382;

    cout.fill  ('0');    
    cout.width ( 4 );
    cout << i;

    return 0;
}
```

## <kbd>[ideoneTest](https://ideone.com/exlkuh)</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar `printf` en lugar de `cout`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int i;
   i = 382;
   printf("%04d\n", i);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: El problema que presenta tu solución es que mezclar `cout` (habitual en c++) con `printf` (heredado de C) puede dar resultados extraños. Así pues tu solución te limita el uso de `cout`. Además `printf` esta mucho mas limitado que `cout`. Pese a eso el negativo que tienes me parece excesivo

Comment: Me pareció válido sugerir una solución usando ``printf`` en lugar de ``cout`` porque el encabezado de la pregunta daba la opción de una respuesta con ``printf``. Me pareció pertinente ya que no obliga a incluir ninguna librería.

De todos modos entiendo la validez de tu comentario

Comment: Tienes que incluir directa o indirectamente `cstdio`. Y no digo que la respuesta sea errónea sino simplemente que puede ser problemática y poco escalable

Comment: +1 porque para C es una buena respuesta. y a veces Algunos buscan respuestas de C en c++

Answer (score 3):

Incluye la librería `iomanip`

```
int i = 382;
std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << i;
```

Poner 0 en un entero no sirve de nada porque se ignoran... Los ceros se añaden al imprimir el valor